# SQL statement to set numbering style for all multiple choice questions in a Moodle course

Tags: sql, moodle

I'm looking for an SQL statement to remove the numbering of choices for all multiple choice questions in a Moodle question category.

(Changing "Number the choices?" from "a.,b.,c.,.." to "No numbering", for all questions in a course, or in a category.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Moodle Developer Forums and got the answer from Stuart Mealor and Tim Hunt ([Moodle in English: Useful SQL Queries?](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=153059)). In short, it is the following:

```
UPDATE mdl_qtype_multichoice_options
SET answernumbering = 'none'
WHERE questionid IN (SELECT id FROM mdl_question WHERE category = 123)
```

The table and field names might depend on the Moodle version. In 2.5.9, the following statement worked for me:

```
UPDATE mdl_question_multichoice
SET answernumbering = 'none'
WHERE question IN
    (SELECT id FROM mdl_question
     WHERE category = 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but probably something like this, backup before you do anything though

```
UPDATE mdl_question_multichoice
SET answernumbering = 'none'
WHERE answernumbering = '123';
```